# How to fetch customer information through an eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have three models: Payment, Booking and Customer. A payment relation belongs to the Booking model and the Booking model belongs to the Customer model.

I need to make a customer relation inside the Payment model, however, they are not related, the only relation between them is through the Booking model.

My code:

```php
public function booking(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class , 'payable_id' , 'id')->with('customer');
    }


// what i need , i need to consume that booking function to get customer info 
// something like this 
public function customer(){
      // consume the booking relation 
      // return customer info
}
```

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that is a [Has One Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) or [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship, depending on your business model.

```php
Class Payment {
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough('Customer', 'Booking');
    }

    // or:

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Customer', 'Booking');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it's wrong. since payment has only one customer.

Comment: In that case, you should use the HasOneThrough relationship. Edited the answer.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan totally agreed

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you want to get customer information through "**booking**" let's say  it is your lookup table where a *customer id* and *payment id* fields exist.

It should look like this

[ERD of table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9anj.png)

In your Booking Model you have should two functions

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'cust_id', 'id');
}

public function payment() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class, 'payable_id', 'id');
}
```

In both your Customer and Payment Models add

```
public function bookings() {
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class, '(cust_id or payable_id respectively)', 'id');
}
```

in case you want to access booking via customer/payment models as well.

Now with those relationships you can access both payment and customer by accessing booking.

e.g.

```
$customers = Booking::all()->with('customer');
$payments = Booking::all()->with('payment');
```

Now you can manipulate all other data for display and/or editing or whatever you need to do with it.

You can also now access a customer's data with all of his/her bookings and payments associated. Below code results a collection of payments based on c

```
$customer = Customer::find(1)->with('bookings')->first();
$payments = $customer->bookings->payment;
```

For more questions feel free to delve in to the Official Laravel documentations.
In answering your question I based it on this.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Hope I helped and cheers!